# Proving $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x} dx$ converges or not

Tags: integration

How can we prove that the following integral:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x} dx$$

converges or not?

I tried using comparison test, but have since found no function to be able to compare the given function to it.

Comment: it is conditionally convergent

Comment: have you tried letting $I(a)=\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x}dx$ then solving using $I'(a)$, I know this works for the same integral but using $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\int_{\pi /2}^{M} \frac {cos x} xdx=\frac {\sin x}x |_{\pi/2}^{M} +\int_{\pi /2}^{M} \frac {sin x} {x^{2}}dx$ and you can now see that the improper Riemann integral $\int_{\pi /2}^{\infty} \frac {cos x} xdx$ exists.

Comment: How did you find that the provided $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^M \frac{\sin{x}}{x^2} dx$ in your solution converges?

Comment: @Jigsaw:  The integral of $1/x^2$ converges, and $-1/x^2 \leq \sin x/x^2 \leq 1/x^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Using the bound $|\int_M^{n} \frac {sin x} {x^{2}} dx| \leq |\int_M^{n} \frac 1{x^{2}} dx| =\frac  1 M -\frac  1n \to 0$ as $n,M\to \infty$ you can see that the improper integral of $\frac {sin x} {x^{2}}$ is convergent.

Comment: How the second term in the answer has changed from the integral form? Can we change the form into the normal form without any constraint? If yes, why we were not able to change the first term into some non integral form at the beginning?